# If a certain patient ID is inputted, I want the data from that patientID to all be deleted from the txt file

Tags: python, file-handling, txt

It says `patientID` is not found even when it's there

```
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/yn/1pr6fyfd6xg_nb7x3x11j6z80000gn/T/ipykernel_11255/2986997272.py in <module>
    187         patients = []
    188         with open(fileName，"a") as f:
--> 189             for line in f:
    190                 values = line.strip().split(",")
    191                 patientID = int(values [0])

UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

I needed it to delete the patient data

[image: Image of Code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) [idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Please take your time to follow the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your post is confusing, as the error message is not related to the rest of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are having a problem reading a file, not related to the data inside. To read a file in Python, you can assign a variable, such as your `f`, to the results of `open()`. This sets `f` as a file descriptor that can be used to manipulate the file. Also, I see that you are using a `a` flag to open the file, which opens the file in append mode and makes it unreadable.

```
# this is the REPL for python, >>>'s and ...'s are code I type
>>> with open('demo.txt', 'r') as f:
...     f.readlines()
...
['this is a demo\n', 'this is line 2\n']
```

with `demo.txt` having the following contents (and newline at the end) (and for those who may be concerned, in CRLF format)

```
this is a demo
this is line 2
```